# Unable to run Airflow Tasks due to execution date and start date

Tags: airflow

Whenever I try to run a DAG, it will be in the running state but the tasks will not run. I have set my start date to datetime.today() and my schedule interval to "* * * * *". Manually triggering a run will start the dag but the task will not run due to:

The execution date is 2017-09-13T00:00:00 but this is before the task's start date 2017-09-13T16:20:30.363268.

I have tried various combinations of schedule intervals (such as a specific time each day) as well as waiting for the dag to be triggered and manual triggers. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try hardcoding the DAG's start date to something like `datetime(2017, 9, 12)`, instead of `datetime.today()`. The [FAQ](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date) has some more details about this.

Comment: if you wish to trigger manually, you can disable by setting schedule_interval:none and trigger dag manually. If you want it to be scheduled, make sure worker and schedular are running. Below settings works fine for me (for every 2 minute run): start_date: datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(minutes=2), schedule_interval: timedelta(minutes=2)

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried all the above suggestions and nothing appears to work. @VinodVutpala using your start date and interval, I still get: 
The execution date is 2017-09-14T00:00:00 but this is before the task's start date 2017-09-14T13:16:33.998064.

However now I also get:
Task instance's dagrun did not exist: Unknown reason.

I wonder if this is a worker issue.

Answer (score 20):

First of all `start_date` is a task attribute; but in general, it is set in `default_args` and used like dag attribute.

The message is very clear, if a task's `execution_date` is before the task's  `start_date`, it can not be scheduled. You can set `start_date` smaller value:

```
import datetime

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)  # hard coded date
}
```

or

```
import airflow

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(7)  # 7 days ago
}
```

From [Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html)

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.
>
> **Let’s Repeat That** The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

So, when you schedule your dag, any dag_run's `execution_date` will be smaller than its start time. For daily, there will be 24 hours difference.

We can say start time = `execution_date` + `schedule_interval`
(start time is not `start_date`, it is just the start time of the dag run)

Comment: "We can say start time = execution_date + schedule_interval"

That would mean that start time > execution_date. Did you mean to have it the other way around? Surely start time is the *first* point on the timeline and all execution_dates come after it.

Comment: I mean by the "start time" is "the start time of a specific dag run". Example: I have a daily scheduled dag, there is a dag run that starts at 2020-11-23T00:00, it's execution_date will be 2020-11-22T00:00. formula: 2020-11-23T00:00 = 2020-11-22T00:00 + 24h (schedule_interval). In other words: DAGs are running periodically, execution_date is the start of the period, and DAG starts to run at end of the period which is "start time" here. (It is not start_date in the code)

Answer (score 3):

google send me here, I had the same problem as you. I was defined the `start_date` as today

```
'start_date': datetime.today()
```

The problem was solved when I used an older date (for example 7 days ago)

```
seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                  datetime.min.time())
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': seven_days_ago,
    'depends_on_past': False,
}
```

I found this Explanation [Airflow Docs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date)

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the schedulers, that worked for me.

Comment: What is the explanation behind this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, for start_date use only static data, not dynamic data.
A dynamic start_date is misleading, and can cause failures when clearing out failed task instances and missing DAG runs. Additionally, if you change the start_date of your DAG you should also change the DAG name.
[source](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dag-best-practices#use-dag-name-and-start-date-properly)